# Сбор информации об отправленном e-mail

Tags: smtp, email

Многие сервисы по рассылке электронных писем предоставляют такие данные как: было ли открыто письмо и был ли осуществлён переход по ссылкам в теле письма. Как можно реализовать подобные механизмы?

Comment: Втсавить картинку по ссылке на свой сайт, если по этой ссылке зафиксирован запрос — значит письмо открыто. Все ссылки соответственно тоже делать на свой сайт, если на них есть запросы — значит по ссылкам кликают

Comment: @andreymal что значит "есть запрос"?

Comment: Значит на сайт из браузера или почтового клиента пришёл HTTP-запрос на скачивание содержимого картинки/ссылки. Любой сайт всегда пишет логи посещений, а значит по этим самым посещениям можно определить факт открытия письма или перехода по ссылке